# Initial values in Duhamels Principle

Tags: heat-equation, wave-equation

I read the following statement in an article about photoacoustic tomography and don't understand a detail about it.

According to Duhamel's Principle, the inhomogeneous equation
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:8}
    \begin{cases}
      p_{tt}-c\Delta_{x}p = f(x) & \text{$t\geq0$,$x\in\mathbb{R}^3$}\\
      p(x,0)=0, p_{t}(x,0)=0 \\ 
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:9}
    \begin{cases}
      p_{tt}-c\Delta_{x}p = 0 & \text{$t\geq0$,$x\in\mathbb{R}^3$}\\
      p(x,0)=f(x), p_{t}(x,0)=0 \\ 
    \end{cases}       
\end{equation}

where $f(x)$ is the original pressure.

I am a bit confused, because as far as I know Duhamel's principle states that the initial values must be chosen exactly the other way around i.e.

$p(x,0)=0, p_{t}(x,0)=f(x)$

Why is it possible to swap the two conditions? Is this always possible?

Comment: It's not easy to tell what's going on unless you tell us exactly what paper it is that you are reading. But you're right that in Duhamel's principle, the $f$ should go with the $p_t$ term. And moreover there is an integration from $0$ to $t$ involved, which you haven't mentioned, so the way you have formulated it neither version is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDE they are talking about is *not* the one that you wrote (with just $f(x)$ on the right-hand side), but their equation (1) which also involves a Dirac delta with respect to the time variable:
$$
p_{tt} - c^2 \Delta p = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x) \, \delta(t) = f(x) \, \delta'(t)
,\qquad
p(x,0)=0
,\qquad
p_t(x,0)=0
.
$$
So $p=q_t$, where $q$ satisfies
$$
q_{tt} - c^2 \Delta q = f(x) \, \delta(t)
,\qquad
q(x,0)=0
,\qquad
q_t(x,0)=0
.
$$
Applying Duhamel's principle to this problem for $q$, you'll only get a contribution from $s=0$ in the integral $\int_{0}^{t} (\cdots) \, ds$, because of the Dirac delta, so $q(x,t)$ is equal to the solution of
$$
q_{tt} - c^2 \Delta q = 0
,\qquad
q(x,0)=0
,\qquad
q_t(x,0)=f(x)
.
$$
And this means that $p=q_t$ satisfies
$$
p_{tt} - c^2 \Delta p = 0
,\qquad
p(x,0)=f(x)
,\qquad
p_t(x,0)=0
.
$$
(Here, the initial condition for $p_t$ comes from $p_t = (q_t)_t = c^2 \Delta q$, which is zero at $t=0$ since $q=0$ at $t=0$.)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Could I ask you one more question? At first I thought I'd understood your answer, but I don't quite understand why q(x,t) is equal to the solution of the homogeneous problem. Could you please elaborate what exactly happens with the Dirac delta in the integral $\int_{0}^{t}$

Comment: Normally in Duhamel's principle you would integrate to get the final solution; for each $s \in [0,t]$, there is one infinitesimally small contribution originating at time $s$, and the solution you seek is the “sum” (= integral) of all these uncountably many infinitesimal contributions. But this $\delta(t)$ thing is basically just notation that the authors are using to say that instead of such an integral, there is only one single finite contribution originating at time zero, and that's the contribution that you get by taking $u_t(x,0)$ equal to what's multiplying the delta, namely $f(x)$.